# Javascript object retaining "old" properties, can't override?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

I have the following code:

```
    const readDataFromSql = () => {
        // going to have to iterate through all known activities + load them here
        let sql = "[...]"
        return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            executeSqlQuery(sql).then((dict) => {
                let loadedData = [];
                for (let key in dict) {
                    let newItemVal = new ItemVal("reading hw", 7121, progress.DONE);
                    loadedData.push(newItemVal);
                }
                resolve(loadedData);
            });
        });
    }
```

ItemVal implementation:

```
class ItemVal {
   constructor(name, time, type) {
      this.name = name
      this.time = time
      this.type = type 
   }
}
```

Let's assume that newItemVal = "reading hwj", 5081, progress.PAUSED when readDataFromSql() first runs.

readDataFromSql() is then again called after some state changes -- where it repulls some information from a database and generates new values. What is perplexing, however, is that when it is called the second time, newItemVal still retains its old properties (attaching screenshot below).

Am I misusing the new keyword? 
[image]

Comment: Your function is already marked as `async`- you don’t need to create a `Promise` object, the JS engine handles that for you.

Comment: @Dai -- I removed the async flag yet am still encountering the persistence issue; it is incredibly weird, as even if I harcoded the loadedData array, the object that is printed out is not the same as what it is set to.

Comment: if you're using console.log and mutating the ItemVal instance, when you check the value in console it may not reflect the value at the point you logged it.  Try to console.log a stringified version or the primitives inside the ItemVal and see if you still see the issue

Comment: @user120242 will try this; whether or not this is the issue, however, this wouldn't really fix the issue of displaying the object, right? (as displaying it would be more logically equivalent to printing it out)

Comment: Can you share the implementation of ItemVal

Comment: Yes! I have edited it in. @ShubhamKhatri

Comment: @dannybess It's impossible to tell the reason this is happening without seeing the code that detects wrong values. In other words, the place where `readDataFromSql` is called. You've also tagged this question as **redux** - maybe the issue is with how you're updating state in there?

Comment: @hlfrmn The place where readDataFromSql is called can't be a suspect, though, as this place simply uses the values returned by loadedData, and loadedData is incorrect in `readDataFromSql`. Redux could be the case -- but neither loadedData nor anything else in this block of code are in the redux state...

Comment: Your wording implies you are mutating the ItemVal properties, but the code does not show where it is done.  You speak of using old properties, but nothing in this code is using a constructed ItemVal's values.  Post the actual code in a runnable form that is causing the problem, because your modified paraphrased code here cannot show the problem you are referring to.  The only recommendation that can be given is to avoid mutating ItemVal and treat all data immutably, and verify the state of the data before and after where you say it is wrong.  It sounds like you are just logging incorrectly.

Comment: From your sample output screenshot, it definitely looks like the values were assigned correctly in the constructor but then mutated later on. Please show us more code around the readDataFromSql function

Answer (score 2):

From what I can see in your example code, you are not mutating existing properties but creating a new object with the `ItemVal` constructor function and adding them to an array, that you then return as a resolved promise. Are you sure the examples you give a correct representation of what you are actually doing

Given that, I'm not sure what could be causing the issue you are having, but I would at least recommend a different structure for your code, using a simpler function for the `itemVal`.

Perhaps with this setup, you might get an error returned that might help you debug your issue.

```
const itemVal = (name, time, type) => ({ name, time, type })

const readDataFromSql = async () => {
  try {
    const sql = "[...]"
    const dict = await executeSqlQuery(sql)

    const loadedData = dict.map((key) =>
      ItemVal("reading hw", 7121, progress.DONE)
    )

    return loadedData
 

  } catch (error) {
    return error
  }
};
```

If the issue is not in the function, then I would assume that the way you handle the data, returned from the `readDataFromSql` function, is where the issue lies. You need to then share more details about your implementation.

Answer (score 0):

```
const readDataFromSql = async () => {
        let sql = "[...]"        
------> await executeSqlQuery(sql).then((dict) => {
```

Use the await keyword instead of creating a new promise.

Comment: I changed to await yet the array values are still "persisting"; any other ideas how this could possibly be the case?

Answer (score 0):

I did some modification and found that below code is working correctly, and updating the new values on each call.

```
const readDataFromSql = () => {     
      return new Promise((resolve, reject) => { 
            let loadedData = [];
                let randomVal = Math.random();
                let newItemVal = new ItemVal(randomVal*10, randomVal*100, randomVal*1000);
                loadedData.push(newItemVal); 
            resolve(loadedData);
    });
}
```

Could you recheck if you are using below line in the code, as it will instantiate object with same properties again and again.

```
let newItemVal = new ItemVal("reading hw", 7121, progress.DONE);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can modify your code as below to simplify the problem.

```
const readDataFromSql = async () => {
// going to have to iterate through all known activities + load them here
let sql = "[...]"       // define sql properly

let result = await executeSqlQuery(sql);

let loadedData = [];
for (let row in result) {
        let newItemVal = new ItemVal(row.name, row.time, row.type);
        loadedData.push(newItemVal);
    }

    return loadedData;
}


class ItemVal {
    constructor(name, time, type) {
        this.name = name
        this.time = time
        this.type = type
    }
}
```

What you are talking about is an issue related to Object mutation in Redux, however, you didn't add any redux code. Anyway, you might be making some mistake while recreating(not mutating) the array.
General solution is the use spread operator as:

```
loadedData = [ ...loadedData.slice(0) , ...newloadedData]
```

Answer (score 0):

In `Dropdown.js` line `188` instead of `console.log`-ing your variable write `debugger;`

This will function as a breakpoint. It will halt your code and you can inspect the value by hovering your mouse over the code BEFORE the `newItemVal` is changed again.

I can see in your screenshot that the `newItemVal` is modified again after you log it.